# Hacking QuickTime player on iPhone's safari with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, mobile, quicktime

Apple used to limit our ideas on its platform.

My concern here is how we could addEventListener which trigger on "click" event within QuickTime player using JavaScript.

Suppose we open the video from HTML5 video tag.

Answer (score 1):

For video file you better use embed tag in html5

```
<embed width="260" height="282" src="'+file location+'" showstatusbar="true" showgotobar="true" showdisplay="true" pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/" type="application/x-mplayer2" name="rTuner" AUTOSTART="false"/>
```

For audio

```
<embed  height="50" width="180" name="plugin" src="'+file location+'" type="audio/x-wav" controls AUTOSTART="false"/>
```

Comment: Thank Karthic. Is there a way we can attach "click" event within QuickTime player on iPhone's Safari.

Answer (score 1):

I have list of video files

```
$('ul#totalFileList').on('click','.playRecorded',function(){
                        var lessonName = $(this).attr('id')                     if(lessonName.contains(".mov") || lessonName.contains(".mp4") || lessonName.contains(".avi") || lessonName.contains(".wmv")  || lessonName.contains(".wma"))
                        {
                            $('ul#viewOtherFiles').children('li').children('embed').each(function( index ){
                                $('ul#viewOtherFiles').children('li').children('embed').remove();
                            });

                            $(this).after('<embed width="260" height="282" src="'+uploadUrl+lessonName+'" showstatusbar="true" showgotobar="true" showdisplay="true" pluginspage="http://www.microsoft.com/Windows/MediaPlayer/" type="application/x-mplayer2" name="rTuner" AUTOSTART="false"/>');
                        }
});
```

Comment: add class name "playRecorded" for each files.so whenever i click the file, it starts playing within the quick time player

Comment: Good Answer, the main point here i would like to attach 'click' event when the QuickTime is already opened. (Inside QuickTime)

Comment: i used bootstrap accordian in my page.so when i click one video file, suddenly quicktimeplayer opens play the video. Then i click another video file suddenly (already open)quicktimeplayer closed and now another qucktimeplayer opens and play the second video file.......